# Package error classicthesis - Unknown option `floatperchapterpdfspacing'

Tags: classicthesis

I just started configurating classicthesis and only made the neccessary changes in classicthesis-config and the thesis itself.
After fixing a few issues with ngerman babel, it's now working, but exits with errors.

1.
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `floatperchapterpdfspacing' for package`classict
hesis'.

concerning line 92 of classicthesis.sty, which is: \ProcessOptions\relax. This option was never given to the package? Here a piece of unchanged code (except commenting out the duplicate line, which didn't help) until this line:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{classicthesis}[2011/01/24 v2.9 Typographic Style for a classic-looking thesis]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
    \newboolean{@tocaligned} % the left column of the toc will be aligned (no indention)
    \newboolean{@eulerchapternumbers} % use AMS Euler for chapter font (otherwise Palatino)
    \newboolean{@drafting} % print version information on pages
    \newboolean{@linedheaders} % chaper headers will have line above and beneath
    \newboolean{@listsseparated} % toggles the vertical space between lof/lot entries of different chapters
    \newboolean{@nochapters} % disable all chapter-specific commands 
    \newboolean{@beramono} % toggle nice monospaced font (w/ bold) + pre-installed 
    \newboolean{@eulermath} % use awesome Euler fonts for math
    \newboolean{@parts} % use part division for the text
    \newboolean{@minionpro} % setup for minion pro font
    \newboolean{@minionprospacing} % use minion pro's textssc for letter spacing
    \newboolean{@pdfspacing} % use pdftex for letterspacing (via microtype)
    \newboolean{@subfig} % setup for preloaded @subfig package
    \newboolean{@a5paper} % use those tiny DIN A5 pages
    \newboolean{@dottedtoc} % page numbers in ToC flushed right
    \newboolean{@listings} % load listings package (if not already) and setup LoL
    \newboolean{@manychapters} % additional space in ToC after chapter number (if two digits are needed)
    \newboolean{@floatperchapter} % additional space in ToC after chapter number (if two digits are needed)

% ********************************************************************
% Options
% ******************************************************************** 
\DeclareOption{tocaligned}{\setboolean{@tocaligned}{true}}
\DeclareOption{eulerchapternumbers}{\setboolean{@eulerchapternumbers}{true}}
\DeclareOption{drafting}{\setboolean{@drafting}{true}}
\DeclareOption{linedheaders}{\setboolean{@linedheaders}{true}}
\DeclareOption{listsseparated}{\setboolean{@listsseparated}{true}}
\DeclareOption{subfigure}{%
    \PackageWarningNoLine{classicthesis}{Package "subfigure" and option "subfigure" are deprecated, used "subfig" instead.}
    \setboolean{@subfig}{true}%
    }
\DeclareOption{subfig}{\setboolean{@subfig}{true}}
\DeclareOption{nochapters}{\setboolean{@nochapters}{true}}
\DeclareOption{beramono}{\setboolean{@beramono}{true}} 
\DeclareOption{eulermath}{\setboolean{@eulermath}{true}} 
\DeclareOption{parts}{\setboolean{@parts}{true}} 
\DeclareOption{a5paper}{\setboolean{@a5paper}{true}}
\DeclareOption{minionpro}{\setboolean{@minionpro}{true}} 
\DeclareOption{minionprospacing}{\setboolean{@minionprospacing}{true}} 
%\DeclareOption{pdfspacing}{\setboolean{@pdfspacing}{true}} 
\DeclareOption{pdfspacing}{\setboolean{@pdfspacing}{true}} 
\DeclareOption{dottedtoc}{\setboolean{@dottedtoc}{true}} 
\DeclareOption{listings}{\setboolean{@listings}{true}}
\DeclareOption{manychapters}{\setboolean{@manychapters}{true}}
\DeclareOption{floatperchapter}{\setboolean{@floatperchapter}{true}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

2.
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
concerning line 172 of classicthesis.sty, which is: \definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}. 
Obviously the package was loaded before, but my search of the other documents for the phrase "xcolor" yielded nothing. Is there another package that loads xcolor beforehand? And should the \RequirePackage code not prevent that?

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % [dvipsnames] 
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55} % chapter numbers will be semi transparent .5 .55 .6 .0
\definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\definecolor{webbrown}{rgb}{.6,0,0}
\definecolor{Maroon}{cmyk}{0, 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}
\definecolor{RoyalBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.50, 0, 0}
\definecolor{Black}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Thanks! =)

Comment: Welcome, where is the original license and copyright note of the original package gone?

Comment: you are right. I skimmed through the files, due to their length and number. copying this part too may have helped recognizing the old vesion: % Copyright (C) 2011 Andr\'e Miede http://www.miede.de

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. floatperchapter, pdfspacing are two options, and the reason why latex sees them as one might be a missing comma.
2. you have a 6 years old version of classicthesis.sty; all versions past 3.0 have had this as

`\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}` 
which at least avoids such clashes (but gives somewhat unpredictable results)

Check this branch https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/src/e02199

Comment: perfect. this version works far better, both problems solved. thanks!